# Get information from external website using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have found a simple jQuery snippet that pulls information from an external website. However, I am struggling to convert it to run purely on JavaScript. I think I am on the right path, but I am not sure how to filter the pulled information and display only the text inside the h1 tag. I would be really grateful if someone can help out or provide me with a hint to what should I do next. Thank you in advance!

This is the jQuery code that is fully functional:

```js
$.ajax({
    url:'https://enable-cors.org',
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data){
           $('#content').html($(data).find('h1').html());        
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

and this is the JavaScript that I have so far:

```js
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://enable-cors.org", true);
request.onload = () => {console.log(request.responseText)}
request.send();
```

Comment: Take a look at using more modern `fetch()` rather than `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation, I have to research it further as I am not familiar with this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

(1) turn the response into a document that you can navigate, so you can get to the `<h1>`

(2) populate the `#content` with what's in that found `<h1>`

```js
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://enable-cors.org", true);
request.onload = () => {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(request.responseText, 'text/html');
  document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = doc.querySelector('h1').innerHTML;
}
request.send();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you deeply for the provided solution. It works like a charm. I have to research further the "DOMParser" as this is completely new to me. Once again thank you!